# semilinear parabolic pde-reference

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, semigroup-of-operators

i have the following semilinear parabolic problem
$$
\partial_t u(x,t)- \Delta u +F(u)= f(x,t); x \in \mathbb{R}^n, t > 0
$$
$$
u(x,0)=0
$$
with periodic boundary conditions, and $F$ is non linear.

What are the conditions of the non linear term $F$ and the second member $f$ to have a unique classical solution to this problem? Or there exists an reference for this result?